# How to install simpleSAMLphp framework with Zend framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, simplesamlphp

I am working on an application that was built in Zend framework 1. I want to install simpleSAMLphp as a service provider for it and trying to figure how best to do this.

I'm considering a couple of options:

Install it outside the application
(e.g. /var/www/myapp/simplesamlphp where my app's files are at /var/www/myapp/simplesamlphp). This is how it seems it's done in the installation tutorials. I guess this would work with some adjustments to the autoloading so it can pickup the SimpleSamlphp classes. I'm using composer to install dependencies so I can perhaps add the SimpleSAML folder to the class tree - not tried this yet. Or should I use the SimpleSAMLphp autoload file?

simplesamlphp-composer
I sees there is an option install with composer? So, if so, it will go within my application folder and files. However, I've tried this and not sure how to get composer to pick up the SimpleSAML classes. Anyone had much use of this method? I tried doing composer dump-autoload but it didn't add them. I guess I need to do more.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to use simpleSAMLphp with ZF1. Even just a point in the correct direction regarding where best to put files. We want to role this installation out to all our websites eventually so something that is easy to setup would be best I guess. I do like the composer approach but didn't have much luck with it. Previously the project used CAS with a phpCAS client - that was installed using composer which was quite convenient.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used ZF 1 and had following structure

```
/lib/Zend/ -- ZF
/lib/Zend.php 
/lib/MyCompany/ -- my classes that supports ZF autolaod 
/lib/ANyOtherZFCompatible
/lib/external/ -- any other libs that don't support ZF convention
```

I would  put SimpleSAML into /lib/external/simpleSAML/
and at the beginning of your main file

require_once('/lib/external/simpleSAML/lib/_autoload.php'); and try to use init some SAML classes.